# create a wlan through existing wlan

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Is there some device/setting where i go to some place where there is an existing WLAN. I would then connect some WLAN router/special device to that WLAN to gain internet access. Now i want that device to create another WLAN to which my other devices can connect. Thus i could setup my devices to connect to my WLAN router/device and only that device would need to connect to the existing other device.

In best case as a fallback some 3G card/umts stick could be used in that device as well.

thanks

//Edit: adding some information about use case. I have multiple devices. I want to connect them only once - to my WLAN router. That router would handle to go to the internet. And in most of my cases that internet is available via WLAN. As there are a bunch of devices i want to avoid to enter the credentials into all of them.

As for operating system - the devices are a mix of ios, android and windows phone. I would have some laptop with Windows 7/8.

Comment: There are ways to do that, but what operating system are you using? Windows, OS X, Linux?

Comment: You mean something like `[Your devices] --> [Your AP] --> [Existing AP]`? Why can't you just connect to the existing access point? See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask): one of the criteria is to only ask about actual problems that you face. What is your actual problem?

Comment: ok sorry - should have added my use case. edited my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is "multiple SSID support" - it's a feature of the router, so if you don't see anything about it in the manual or configuration pages, it's likely not possible with your current unit.

Most cheap consumer level routers only support a single SSID.  Some SOHO/low-end business routers support multiple ones, typically for a guest and corporate wireless, such as the Netopia DSL modem/router series.

If your existing router has LAN ports, you could always connect a second wireless router to it, and disable DHCP, the firewall, and routing on the second device (because the first router will handle all that) and configure the second wireless router's AP to however you need.

Comment: thanks - exactly what i was looking for with the multiple SSID support